# Настройка Com портов на виртуальной машине

Tags: windows, vmware, rdp

На сервере развёрнута виртуальная машина ESXI, в ней поставлен образ Windows xp. Включена функция подключение к удалённому рабочему столу, и к Win xp подключаюсь удалённо. Нужно удалённую машину вставить COM кабель, и передать сигнал по RDP на тот же номер COM порта на виртуальной машине. Рис.1. В RDP включил функцию передачи последовательных портов, но на виртуальной машине они не появились в диспетчере устройств. В настройках виртуальной машины можно добавить последовательные порты, но не совсем понятно какие именно нужно выбирать: Use output file, Use physical serial port, Use named pipe, Use network, если какой либо из них, то не понимаю как его настроить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что есть на клиенте?

Comment: @eri В клиентский компьютер вставлена аппаратура которая работает через COM порт. Нужно чтобы клиент со вставленной апаратурой подключился к виртуалке по RDP, и там запустил программу которая на COM порт будет слать сигнал, а аппаратура принимала его.

Comment: Забей на rdp и виртуалку. Запусти ser2net или аналог

Answer (score 0):

> В настройках виртуальной машины можно добавить последовательные порты, но не совсем понятно какие именно нужно выбирать: Use output file, Use physical serial port, Use named pipe, Use network, если какой либо из них, то не понимаю как его настроить.

Виртуалка тут участия принимать не должна никакого, эти настройки трогать не нужно.

Нужно чтобы клиент, после того как подключится, набрал

```
net use com1 \\tsclient\com1
```

в командной строке сервера, и тогда у него на сервере появится его локальный порт com1

Comment: В диспечере устройств не появилось новое устройство, где я могу их посмотреть?

Comment: А команда хотя бы выполнилась без ошибок?

Comment: Была ошибка 85,то что устройство уже используется, но я просто указал другой номер com порта

Comment: Покажите переделанную вами команду

Comment: net use com2 \\tsclient\com1

Comment: А на клиенте устройство прицеплено в COM1 ?

Попробуйте тогда воспользоваться вашим софтом, и подключиться к COM2

Comment: Как я понял, я буду использовать COM1 на клиентском компьютере, а отображаться он будет на сервере как COM2? верно? мне не столь важен номер порта, а нужно именно факт проброса, как я могу посмотреть, успешно я пробросил или нет? где я могу на сервере посмотреть список портов?

Comment: Да, вы все поняли правильно. Лучший способ проверить - воспользоваться вашим софтом и устройством